# Bootstrap - Carousel doesn't work. Show all pictures but without animation

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am new and i just started to learn bootstrap. I found one problem for now and im trying to solve it about one hour. My carousel gallery doesnt work. It shows all pictures at once.

This is my code:
`

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div id="myowncarousel" class="carousel slide">
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                          <li data-target="#myowncarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                          <li data-target="#myowncarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                          <li data-target="#myowncarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        </ol>
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="item active">
                            <img src="img/banner_1.png" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                            <img src="img/banner_2.png" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                            <img src="img/banner_3.png" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myowncarousel" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="icon-prev"></span></a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myowncarousel" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="icon-next"></span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
```

`
I would be very greatful for your help!

EDIT:

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="30" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
        <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      </head>
      <body>
...

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
```

This is how i'm loading bootstrap files. I hope it's ok.

Comment: have you verified that bootstrap is working on your site? If so, you should inspect element on your item and see if there is a style overwriting the css rule `.carousel-inner > .item {display: none;}`. Also, I don't think the js will fire unless you have `data-ride="carousel"` on your element with `class="carousel slide"`

Comment: your code is fine and if you correctly loaded js and css files then it should work, so you probably didn't load something in right way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `Bootstrap v4` in your imports, but your html code for `Bootstrap 3`

So, to solve the problem you should:

- Add Bootstrap 3 to your imports
- Change your code to bootstrap 4

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/teleginzhenya/9c8rakfh/)

Comment: Oh... thank you so much. I didn't know that there is a difference beetween code bootstrap 3 and 4. I fixed it now with your help. Thank you once more!!